# IOptions<Applications> does not contain definition 'Options' in ASP.NET 5 Beta 8

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Problem**

I am having trouble with upgrading my beta7 application to beta8. I orginally had over 50 errors, but I have basically gotten it down to two persistent errors remaining that I have been unable to resolve. One is with Options.

**Options Missing Error**

Here is the error:

> Error  CS1061  'IOptions<ApplicationSettings>' does not contain a definition for 'Options' and no extension method 'Options' accepting a first argument of type 'IOptions<ApplicationSettings>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SampleProject.DNX 4.5.1

Here is the code:

```
private IOptions<ApplicationSettings> _applicationSettings;

// Authenticate user credentials against Active Directory
bool isAuthenticated = await Authentication.ValidateCredentialsAsync(
                domainController: _applicationSettings.Options.DomainController,
                port: _applicationSettings.Options.DomainControllerSslPort,
                domain: _applicationSettings.Options.DomainController,
                username: model.eID,
                password: model.Password);
```

The specific problem above is with `_applicationSettings.Options.DomainController`

**Attempts:**

I tried the following things:

- I tried using intellisense and GitHub to find where 'Options' for IOptions went, but I have been unsuccessful.
- I also tried `dnu restore` just to be sure the upgrade didn't do something strange with my project.json lock.

Now that beta8 is feature complete, I may rewrite significant portions of my project. However, for now I need to resolve these errors so that I can compile the project again. Any help, assistance, and advice rendered would be greatly appreciated.

**Note**: I edited this to one question based on feedback

Comment: @DavidG Thank you for the edit sir. A good day to you. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Options` property of `IOptions<T>` was renamed to `Value`. Try:

```
_applicationSettings.Value
```

Also see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/issues/31).

Comment: Thank you sir. So I can become more self sufficient. Is there an easier way to find closed issues on Github? I feel bad that I completely missed this during my search. My issue regarding EF7 still remains and any assistance would be greatly appreciated. You sir, are the best.

Comment: @hlyates there is a [global announcements repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues) where breaking changes are logged. However, not _every_ change is logged there. I guess your best option is then to look at the issue of the corresponding repos. [Like here for example](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues?q=milestone%3A7.0.0-beta8)

Comment: @hlyates also, I think that you should split up the Options and Entity Framework questions into separate questions.