# ASP.NET Core read config IOptions controller not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to read the appsettings.json file with the strongly type class and pass that as a parameter to controller. However its not working. Here is the code.

**appsettings.json file:**

```js
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "ApplicationName": "TestApp"
    }
}
```

**AppSettings Class:**

```cs
public class AppSettings
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}
```

**Injecting in Startup Class:**

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddOptions();            
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

    }
```

**Controller:**

```cs
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appsettings;


    public ValuesController(IOptions<AppSettings> appsettings)
    {
        _appsettings = appsettings;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return _appsettings.Options.ApplicationName;
    }
}
```

The startup program is successfully getting executed. However, the controller constructor or default get method is not called.

It is working, If I remove the (IOptions appsettings)  from the controller constructor.

What's wrong with my code.

Comment: Do you get any exception or error in your console? If it's not calling the constructor, it means it can't resolve it, so there should be some exception with more information

Comment: Hi TSeng, 

Thank you for the response. I don't find any error while building and at runtime. Can you help me how can I find the error, debug steps ?

Answer (score 1):

IOptions.Options was renamed to IOptions.Value in beta8.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348852/ioptionsapplications-does-not-contain-definition-options-in-asp-net-5-beta-8).

Changing your Get action from:

```
return _appsettings.Options.ApplicationName;
```

to:

```
return _appsettings.Value.ApplicationName;
```

should fix that issue.

***UPDATE 3/8/2016***

The other issue I see here is that you're calling the `Get` action the "default" action, but the default routing in ASP.Net Core looks for an `Index` action on the controller.

You can configure the route in `Startup.cs` to look for a `Get` action by default instead of an `Index` action by modifying the `Configure` function to include something like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Get}/{id?}");
    });
```

The default implmentation uses the template `template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"` which is why it looks for an `Index` action.

Your other options would be to change your `Get` function to an `Index` function, explicitly specify the `Get` action in the url when you visit the site (ex. http://localhost/Values/Get), or specify the action name for the `Get` method in your controller like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Index")]
public string Get()
{
    return _appsettings.Value.ApplicationName;
}
```